# How to send automated emails?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working in C# and Sql server. I have a table Email that contains fields from, to, subject, body, CC, BCC etc. When something happens in it saves the notification. I want to send the mail notification that newly inserted in Email table automatically. Is there is a way in SQL Server??? Which send emails automatically and deletes the record from the table. OR what is the efficient way for this task (from C#code or else).

Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about two problems - 
1. Send email from c#
2. Delete from table

For #1, refer here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is set up your sql server to have sql Mail and then use a trigger against your table to fire the mail event and then delete the row.

Here's how to configure your sever for sql mail
[SQL Mail Config](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/how-do-i-send-e-mail-from-sql-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("address@gmail.com", "Support");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress(user.email, user.username);
            const string subject = "Processing";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = dataToSend
            })
            {
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Model.Message = "Exception Occured During Mail Sending";
        }
```